# Complex SQL Server query with group by and/or distinct and pivot

Tags: sql-server, group-by, pivot

I have a table (`UserAction`) with the following structure:

```
UserActionPK - unique primary key of the UserAction table
AgencyCode - unique name for an agency
EditedKEY - key of a table edited by the user
UserName - name of the user that edited the record
EditedDate - day on which the edit was made
```

I need to query this data and end up with a pivoted data set with a column for the AgencyCode, and one column for each of a set of users (let's say [JohnDoe], [JoeSmith], [SomeGuy]).  In each user's column, it will list the total number of UserActions that user did.  Ex/

```
AgencyCode   JohnDoe   JoeSmith   SomeGuy
ABC          1         3          4
DEF          0         7          2
```

However, there is one special case.  If a user performed multiple actions in a single day (EditedDate) on the same exact record (EditedKEY), then it should only count as 1 action.  For example, if JohnDoe edited a record with an EditedKEY of "XXX" on 1/1/2013 1 time, and then edited that same EditedKEY record of "XXX" on 1/2/2013 3 times, those should only count as 2 edits towards the total.  I essentially need to group just the EditedDate values before pivoting it.  Note, the EditedKEY value is a guid, so it will always be unique even between agencies.

I have a query that will get the data I need and pivot it, but without grouping the UserActions with the same EditedDate, UserName and AgencyCode:

```
select * from
(
    select UserActionKEY, AgencyCode, EditedDate, UserName
    from UserAction
    where EditedDate >= @FromDate
    and EditedDate <= @ToDate
) Pivot1
pivot
(
    count(UserActionKEY) 
    for UserName in 
    (
        [JohnDoe],
        [JohnSmith],
        [SomeGuy],
    )
) Pivot2
```

How can I get it to group these actions by day/user/agency?

UPDATE - Here is some sample data as requested:

```
UserActionPK                            AgencyCode  EditedKEY                               UserName    EditedDate
0F573329-0C83-44B8-AD9A-808D8795FCCF    ABC         521A63CD-AEEF-44BF-BDCB-EE96373AC39A    JohnDoe     3/11/2013
36321DB6-DA1B-430E-B85C-36372088860E    ABC         521A63CD-AEEF-44BF-BDCB-EE96373AC39A    JohnDoe     3/11/2013
BDC9B165-CC93-409A-BEAE-3365709F6E54    ABC         042D633F-47AC-4A5C-BE3B-B179E01AD5C9    JohnDoe     3/11/2013
2475344C-80DD-4898-A7CD-B41B2593F0FE    DEF         F6016422-BB24-4B39-A735-BCD1206AEA4A    JohnDoe     3/11/2013
3CD7B9BB-428A-45E9-B254-8A2FD502B9F7    DEF         C9A028F6-6E1A-4FD6-A549-D932BC20AA88    JohnDoe     3/11/2013
B0348158-1455-42DF-81EB-29704F08E920    ABC         6937C16A-752A-4D69-BBE9-932015B8C137    JohnDoe     3/12/2013
F1C5950D-05D2-48B6-BFC3-1C32FD970F76    ABC         521A63CD-AEEF-44BF-BDCB-EE96373AC39A    JohnDoe     3/12/2013
502F67A2-6448-48FB-8BFE-74D21592BA48    ABC         B3371961-06EE-4CD3-9373-87102EB793FA    JoeSmith    3/11/2013
E797DFE0-8693-44FC-821F-46B745B37533    ABC         79E1F21F-C7D3-4F8C-8D51-536C34FF84D4    JoeSmith    3/11/2013
```

In this example, the JohnDoe column should have a count of 4 actions for agency "ABC" even though he has 5 records for that agency, because he has 2 actions for the same "EditedKEY" (521A63CD-AEEF-44BF-BDCB-EE96373AC39A) that day, which only counts as 1 action.

Comment: Can you post some data from your table?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than a straight `COUNT(...)`, you want to do a SELECT DISTINCT on the grouping criteria plus an additional field `Value = 1`. Then perform a `SUM(Value)` in place of your `COUNT(...)`.

Answer (score -1):

This kind of pivot is usually best done with client application code, rather than in SQL. SQL code needs to know at the front end how many and the names of the result columns at the beginning of the query.